# What is "Just Here for the Hat" for?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

What is the meaning of **the entire site collectively has at least 20
distinct hats** in the below line?

> Own any hat while the entire site collectively has at least 20
>   distinct hats

Does that mean that only 20 hats have been awarded till now or .... Idk?

I like how it looks though... The trophy makes me feel like I was rewarded something very rare :P

Comment: I wish there was a dunce-hat, because I still don't understand this hat... And yes, I read the two answers... I mean why would I need to wait until 20 hat types were handed out and I have at least one hat to get this hat?

Comment: I understand how/when you get the hat but the reason/purpose/meaning of this hat is a mystery. But perhaps there no reason to expect a reason/purpose/meaning - hats are just for fun. Or?

Comment: @sjngm I think the reason it's only to make fun (and to make the users think about it and generate meta discussion ;) ). That the community earns collectively 20 hats it's practically negligible, so when you win your first hat you've this as an extra WTH prize.

Comment: I don't even know what a hat is, but I guess I have one.

Comment: My "hat" is actually a face mask. I guess badges and points are getting boring?

Comment: @albciff Negligible for SO, but not for some of the smaller communities.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It means exactly what it says. If you have a hat, while the other members of the same community have at least 20 (different types of) hats, you'll get this hat.

Or, if you understand SQL:

```sql
USE <the database corresponding to your SE community>;

(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT hatname) FROM awardedhats) >= 20 AND
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM awardedhats WHERE userid = <your user ID>) >= 1
```

Here, `awardedhats` is a table with two columns; the user ID and the name of the hat.

Comment: Oh, So when I said **that only 20 hats have been awarded till now** I was correct?

Comment: No, *at least* 20 (types of) hats.

Comment: Yeah, 20 different types of hats I meant... Sry...

Comment: "It means exactly what it says" - IMO it's extremely unclear

Comment: I understood it, though I don't understand the *why* of it. But I guess hats are just for fun anyway, so you have have silly reasons to be awarded a hat.

Comment: So the only case where you **wouldn't** get this hat is if there's only been < 20 distinct hats awarded by the time you own your first...probably a duration of 0.00005 seconds until at least 20 are discovered... At which point you get this hat anyways. "Free Hat" probably would have caused less confusion.

Answer (score 29):

<sub><sub>Added this answer because the accepted one basically said *"It means exactly what it says."* when I wrote it.</sub></sub>

> Own any hat *while the entire site collectively has at least 20 distinct hats*

Take all the hats **everyone** has gotten on the site, and count the number of different hats. If there is 20 or more different hats awarded and you have a hat, the condition is true.

Comment: Looks like an infinite loop to me. Maybe they meant to use `if` ;)